# Automated ansible output parsing in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, warnings

How do you automatically parse ansible warnings and errors in your jenkins pipeline jobs?

I greatly enjoy the power of leveraging in ansible in jenkins when it works.  Upon a failure, the hunt to locate the actual error can be challenging.

I use [WarningsNG](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng) which supports custom parsers (and allows their [programmatic generation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#creating-a-groovy-parser-programmatically))

Do you know of any plugins or addons that already transform these logs into the kind charts similar to [WarningsNG](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng)?

I figured I'd ask as I go off into deep regex land and make my own.

Comment: Have you already considered using [json callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/callback/json.html), or even [ARA](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara#readme)? _(ARA can log to sqlite, so you don't need to run the full server)_

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel . yes, actually and good idea.  I've changed it to forward events to the default callback to ensure the console gets updated and to output the json to a file.  I can then write a parser to make the errors/warnings salient.  I thought the junit might work even better, but both may store secrets outside of credentials-bindings-plugins and whereas I can clean the json parser result by echoing it to console, I cannot do that for junit

Answer (score 0):

One good way to achieve this seems to be the following:

1. select an existing structured output ansible callback plugin ([json](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/callback/json.html), junit and yaml are all viable) . I selected junit as I can play with the format to get a really nice view into the playbook with errors reported in a very obvious way.
2. fork that GPL file (yes, so be careful with that license) to augment with the following:

   - store output as file
   - implement the missing callback methods (the three mentioned above do not implement the v2...item callbacks.
   - forward events to the default or debug callback to ensure operators see something when they execute the plan
3. add a secrets cleaner - if you use jenkins credentials-binding-plugin it will hide secrets from the console, **it will not not hide secrets within stored files**.  You'll need to handle that in your playbook or via some groovy code (if groovy,  `try{...} finally { clean }` seems a good pattern)

## Snippet - forewarding to default callback

```
from ansible.plugins.callback.default import CallbackModule as CallbackModule_default
...
class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'json'

    def __init__(self, display=None):
        super(CallbackModule, self).__init__(display)
        self.default_callback = CallbackModule_default()
...
    def v2_on_file_diff(self, result):
        self.default_callback.v2_on_file_diff(result)
        ... do whatever you'd want to ensure the content appears in the json file
```